# Mysterious rspec errors after Rails upgrade

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I recently tried to upgrade Rails (to `v5.2.2`) in a bunch of my code repos and two of them failed their unit tests after the upgrade. After some digging around and comparing the failed and working versions of `Gemfile.lock` line by line, I discovered upgrading `activestorage` (`v5.2.1` -> `5.2.2`) was the culprit and I was able to replicate it and reverse it. It seems like an issue has been introduced (at least for the tests; I haven't seen this issue using my code in person) where the test suite can't pick up element property updates after a `.click` event. Has anyone encountered this as well? Might this be a bug?

Here's a sample of the error msgs I was getting:

```
1) Notifications notifications drawer when clicking the nav will open the drawer
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector('.notifications-drawer', visible: true)
   expected to find visible css ".notifications-drawer" but there were no matches. Also found "View all notifications", which matched the selector but not all filters.
    # ./spec/features/notifications_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Notifications mark notification as read behavior when a notification is loaded will be marked as read after clicked
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('.notification.read')
   expected to find css ".notification.read" but there were no matches
 # ./spec/features/notifications_spec.rb:140:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here are the two tests that fail after the upgrade:

```
context 'when clicking the nav' do
    before do
        find('.notifications-drawer-link').click
    end
    it 'will open the drawer' do # line 87
        expect(page).to have_selector('.notifications-drawer', visible: true)
    end
    it 'will have a link to all notifications' do
       expect(page).to have_selector('.notifications-drawer-link')
    end
end

context 'when a notification is loaded' do
  it 'will initially be marked as unread' do
    expect(page).to have_css('.notification.unread')
  end

  it 'will be marked as read after clicked' do # line 137
    notify_element = '[data-notify-id="' + mock_notifications[:items][0][:id] + '"]'
    page.find(notify_element).find('.notifications-date-stamp').trigger("click")
    expect(page).to have_css('.notification.read')
  end
end
```

Comment: I found a workaround today... I changed how page elements were referenced from classes to IDs. That works for static/fixed/singleton items on my page but  I’m a bit at a loss to apply this to lists. (I have a list of items that change class from `.unread` to `.read` and the test runs `expect(page).to have_css('.notification.read')`.)

Comment: You can use `:first-child` and `:nth-child` selectors to click a given element in the list.